# PHP website grinds to halt for an hour, then runs fine....how to debug?

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, mysql, php, tmp

I have a PHP website which uses $_SESSION variables. It runs on Apache, Mysql and Ubuntu 14.04 on a very resourceful server (Amazon EC2 - M3.X-large)

For some unknown reason, the website virtually grinds to a halt every so often, and I don't know why. When this occurs, very few people are visiting the website, and server load is very low. Restarting Apache & MySQL does nothing, however, after about an hour the website speed returns to normal. Restarting my entire server also temporarily fixes the problem, but after a few days the problem reoccurs.

My question is - what could be causing this problem, and what can I do to debug / fix it? Like I said - traffic is very low when the problem occurs so I don't think apache / php require more resources. I think the problem runs deeper. Could the amount of session data being saved be causing the issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i doubt it's the amount of session data.  while the problem is happening try to analyze what's going on.  check the memory usage with `top` check the web logs for hits to particular scripts; check mysql with `> show processlist;` check your bandwidth by testing the web server from the local server vs remote, etc, hopefully you find the next clue, good luck.

Comment: I think the downvotes here are responses to the "why" question, which is broad and impossible for us to answer from the information you provided.  But "how can I debug" seems like a good question to me, and it should be the focus here. Title revised to reflect that.

Comment: Ok fair enough. So Andrew - any ideas on how to de-bug??

Comment: Have you checked any logs at the time of the issue? @user16081-JoeT has given some information on how to debug, you could also look at using ```strace``` to get more information on what processes are doing at this time. I'll be happy to help more but you'll probably need to provide a little more information.

Comment: Yes, I have checked the logs but I can see anything that is giving me any clues. Looking at 'top' and 'apachetop' doesn't shed any light either. However, next time it occurs I will look at using 'strace' and check whats going on with bandwidth etc. Thanks for the tips guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another useful tool is iotop, although its possible that (since this is a VM) that its nothing on your system causing the slowdown but resource consumption on the virtualization host / storage. In addition to the tools already mentioned you might want to have a look at hprof and compare the profiles outside and during a performance incident.